# Using openrc and using logrotate causes logging to stop working using Alpine Linux

Tags: logrotate, openrc

I'm using a very vanilla openrc service to run a Go application I wrote that spits out logging data to stdout which was working perfectly fine before I enabled `logrorate` on my application's log files. It appears to rotate the logs but after a certain point after the log file has been truncated my Go application stops logging to the file completely. It appears to work again when I restart the service.

My openrc service file:

```
#!/sbin/openrc-run

name="My Server"
description="My Server Written in Go"
command="/usr/bin/server"
command_args="/etc/${RC_SVCNAME}/${RC_SVCNAME}.conf"
pidfile="/var/run/${RC_SVCNAME}.pid"
command_background="yes"
output_log="/var/log/${RC_SVCNAME}/${RC_SVCNAME}.log"
error_log="/var/log/${RC_SVCNAME}/${RC_SVCNAME}.log"


depend() {
    use net localmount logger dns
        need net
        after keepalived firewall
}

start_pre() {
    checkpath --directory /etc/${RC_SVCNAME}
}
```

My `logrotate` config.

```
/var/log/server/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
}
```

Do I need to do anything to my application for it to be aware of the log rotation?

Answer (score 1):

I am no logrotate master, but you can get logrotate to restart the service with:

```
/var/log/server/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty

    postrotate
        /etc/init.d/server --quiet --ifstarted restart || true
    endscript
}
```